# Garage keypad and remote won’t work together

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a Genie Pro 1024 garage opener and have a genie outdoor keypad and generic universal remote opener for the car. I first programmed the keypad and it worked great. Then I programmed the remote and both work, but after a couple days the keypad stops working. When I reprogram the keypad, both work but then the remote stops working. It keeps going back and forth based on the last one programmed. How to I have both work?

Comment: Have you tried changing the batteries in the devices?

Comment: I don't know why the keypad originally stopped working, but it sounds like you may be clearing all codes when you're programming a device. Be sure you're _adding_ a device. (I recently had that problem with my car's keys. It's a different procedure for each.) Let us know how that goes.